# If I bountied a question and then answered it myself, why does my account not get the bounty back?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I recently bountied a question of mine and got the answer to the question, so I answered my own question. Basically, I asked the question on two sites and bountied both of them. One person on another site answered my question, so I gave them the bounty. I then answered the question on the other site to tell the users I knew the answer and whatnot. I never go the bounty back (even though I never expected to).

What are the reasons behind this? I can't find anything in the [bounty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) info page that SE has.

Comment: From the second paragraph of the page you linked: _"A bounty is a special reputation award given to answers. It is funded by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, and is **non-refundable**."_

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot the fact it's given in advance and no on completion sort of shows it's not really a 'bounty' like an IRL bounty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Part of what you're "paying for" with a bounty is for higher question
> visibility and increased answerer motivation. A bounty does **not**
> guarantee a response and is **not refunded** if none are received.

> #### Can I award a bounty to my own answer?
>
> No. This used to be possible, [but it has been
> disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97802/162827).

- Meta SE FAQ post: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/162827)

Comment: And **"Can I award a bounty to my own answer?** *No. This used to be possible, but it has been disabled. The +50 (or whatever bounty amount was allocated) award button simply won't show beside your own answers. (On past bounties awarded to one's own answers, the user would not get the reputation back, and the bounty would be displayed as +0, “this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation”.)*

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for mentioning that. I've included it in the answer.